# Error in performing bluetooth file transfer in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth

I created an app for Transfer of file from bluetooth in android but unfortunately my app crashes
Following is my main source code and log of error.I have a file named "hi.txt" in my sdcard. 
Kindly guide where i a going wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        {     
        ListView listViewPaired;
        ListView listViewDetected;
        ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
        Button buttonSearch, buttonOn, buttonDesc, buttonOff;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter, detectedAdapter, mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
        static HandleSeacrh handleSeacrh;

        BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
        BluetoothClass bdClass;
        ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
        private ButtonClicked clicked;
        ListItemClickedonPaired listItemClickedonPaired;
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
        ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
        ListItemClicked listItemClicked;
        UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            listViewDetected = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetected);
            listViewPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
            buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
            buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
            buttonDesc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDesc);
            buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
            arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            clicked = new ButtonClicked();
            handleSeacrh = new HandleSeacrh();
            arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            /*
             * the above declaration is just for getting the paired bluetooth devices;
             * this helps in the removing the bond between paired devices.
             */
            listItemClickedonPaired = new ListItemClickedonPaired();
            arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
            detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
            mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
            listViewDetected.setAdapter(detectedAdapter);
            listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();
            detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStart();
            getPairedDevices();
            buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
            buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
            buttonDesc.setOnClickListener(clicked);
            buttonOff.setOnClickListener(clicked);
            listViewDetected.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
            listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickedonPaired);
        }

        private void getPairedDevices()
         {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevice.size() > 0)
              {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) 
                 {
                    arrayListpaired.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class ListItemClicked implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener 
         {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);

                Log.i("Log", "The dvice : " + bdDevice.toString());

                Boolean isBonded = false;
                try {
                    isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                    if (isBonded) {

                        Log.i("Log", "Paired");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: " + isBonded);        
            }
        }

        public void btSend()
        {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/hi.txt";

            File file = new File(path);

            BluetoothSocket socket= null;
            try 
              {
                socket = bdDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
                socket.connect();
             } 
            catch (IOException e) 
             {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, path);
            values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION,bdDevice.getAddress());
            values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
            Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
            values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
            getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI,values);
        }



        class ListItemClickedonPaired implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                bdDevice = arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.get(position);
                try {
                    Boolean removeBond = removeBond(bdDevice);
                    if (removeBond) {
                        arrayListpaired.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    Log.i("Log", "Removed" + removeBond);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice)
         {
            Boolean bool = false;
            try {
                Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
                Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
                Class[] par = {};
                Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
                Object[] args = {};
                bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);//, args);
            } catch (Exception e) 
               {
                Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bool.booleanValue();
        };


        public boolean removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice) throws Exception 
        {
            Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Method removeBond = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");
            Boolean returnValue = (Boolean)removeBond.invoke(btDevice);
            return returnValue.booleanValue();
        }


        public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
                throws Exception 
        {
            Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
            Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
            return returnValue.booleanValue();
        }


        class ButtonClicked implements View.OnClickListener
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                    case R.id.buttonOn:
                        onBluetooth();
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonSearch:
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                        startSearching();
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonDesc:
                        makeDiscoverable();
                        break;
                    case R.id.buttonOff:
                        offBluetooth();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
         {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Message msg = Message.obtain();
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searching for devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    try {
                        //device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                        //device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", boolean.class).invoke(device);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("Log", "Inside the exception: ");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (arrayListBluetoothDevices.size() < 1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                    {                                           // device to the arraylist.
                        detectedAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        boolean flag = true;    // flag to indicate that particular device is already in the arlist or not
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListBluetoothDevices.size(); i++) {
                            if (device.getAddress().equals(arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(i).getAddress())) {
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        if (flag == true) {
                            detectedAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                            arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                            detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        private void startSearching()
         {
            Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }

        private void onBluetooth() 
        {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                bluetoothAdapter.enable();
                Log.i("Log", "Bluetooth is Enabled");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        private void offBluetooth() 
          {
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
             {
                bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

     private void makeDiscoverable() 
           {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
            Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
        }

        class HandleSeacrh extends Handler
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what)
                {
                    case 111:

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

**Log file:**

```
  13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo
    11-16 18:01:45.587 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
    11-16 18:01:45.587 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/ActivityThread: setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17915: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17919: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    11-16 18:01:45.637 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getTotalMemory ()J
    11-16 18:01:45.647 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/dalvikvm: GetMethodID: not returning static method Landroid/os/Process;.getFreeMemory ()J
    11-16 18:01:45.687 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    11-16 18:01:45.687 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 439: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    11-16 18:01:45.687 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    11-16 18:01:45.687 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    11-16 18:01:45.687 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 461: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    11-16 18:01:45.687 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    11-16 18:01:45.787 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/BluetoothAdapter: 1112941536: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
    11-16 18:01:45.837 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    11-16 18:01:45.837 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.07
    11-16 18:01:45.837 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 03/30/15 Mon
    11-16 18:01:45.837 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: 
    11-16 18:01:45.837 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: 
    11-16 18:01:45.837 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: 
    11-16 18:01:45.837 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: 
    11-16 18:01:45.897 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    11-16 18:01:46.037 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@424fa760 time:8721552
    11-16 18:01:48.687 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Log: Bluetooth is Enabled
    11-16 18:01:48.717 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/Toast: From com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo, go ahead.
    11-16 18:01:50.267 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:8725789
    11-16 18:01:50.297 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Log: Discoverable 
    11-16 18:01:52.337 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@424fa760 time:8727857
    11-16 18:01:53.227 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Log: in the start searching method
    11-16 18:01:54.717 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/Toast: From com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo, go ahead.
    11-16 18:01:54.727 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/Toast: From com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo, go ahead.
    11-16 18:01:57.917 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Log: The dvice : 24:EC:99:5C:FA:8C
    11-16 18:01:57.947 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo I/Log: The bond is created: false
    11-16 18:01:57.957 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
    11-16 18:01:57.967 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/BluetoothSocket: connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[67]}
    11-16 18:01:58.567 13567-13567/? W/: [ColorAdjust] gammamode=2, cemode=10
    11-16 18:01:58.567 13567-13567/? W/: [ColorAdjust] temp_gammavalue=2, temp_cevalue=10
    11-16 18:01:58.567 13567-13567/? W/: [ColorAdjust] Don't setGamma!
    11-16 18:01:58.567 13567-13567/? W/: [ColorAdjust] Don't setCe!
    11-16 18:01:58.567 13567-13567/? W/: [ColorAdjust] Set temp_prefer temp_ce!
    11-16 18:02:02.277 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:574)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:585)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:326)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo.MainActivity.btSend(MainActivity.java:163)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo.MainActivity$ListItemClicked.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:146)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1115)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2928)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3691)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-16 18:02:02.287 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    11-16 18:02:02.297 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    11-16 18:02:02.297 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    11-16 18:02:02.297 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-16 18:02:02.307 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    11-16 18:02:02.307 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416d9d58)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo, PID: 13170
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppProvider uri content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp from pid=13170, uid=10137 requires android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_SHARE, or grantUriPermission()
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:468)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1190)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo.MainActivity.btSend(MainActivity.java:178)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo.MainActivity$ListItemClicked.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:146)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1115)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2928)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3691)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    11-16 18:02:02.317 13170-13170/com.example.toshiba.bluetoothdemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    '
```

Comment: already present, below the code.

Answer (score 0):

Read this line in logcat

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppProvider uri content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp from pid=13170, uid=10137 requires android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_SHARE, or grantUriPermission()
```

This is your issue, add the android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_SHARE permission to your manifest

I should add that this might not be your only error but it is the one causing this specific crash

Comment: i have already added the required permission in androidManifest file..still it is giving the same error

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388503/android-bluetooth-print-stopped-working-on-4-1

Comment: I replaced contents value code with the following code but still i am getting an error while sending the file from app stating"Request cant be handled correctly":

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: What is the receiver type of device you using? Because i see the log "The bond is created : false" which means createBond() is returning false. That means returnvalue is false due to this line "Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice)"