# Send file via bluetooth to connected device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to send txt file to connected device via bluetooth.

I found an answer here: [Android bluetooth print stopped working on 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388503/android-bluetooth-print-stopped-working-on-4-1) ([Blog](http://innodroid.com/blog/post/how-to-print-via-bluetooth-on-android))

After getting proper device a broadcast is send to notify that device was selected:

```
private void sendDevicePickedIntent(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_DEVICE_SELECTED);
    intent.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, device);

    if (mLaunchPackage != null &amp;&amp; mLaunchClass != null) {
        intent.setClassName(mLaunchPackage, mLaunchClass);
    }

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

The problem there is that `android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED`is a [special broadcast which only system can send](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) so `sendBroadcast(intent);` method throws `SecurityException` saying

> Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.bluetooth.devicepicker.action.DEVICE_SELECTED

Are there any workarounds or other ways to send files?